# Appending multiple values of a json into a Single Pandas column using python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have trouble in getting values from a Json and storing in a Dataframe.
My Json looks like

```
{
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations",
      "id": "1",
      "fields": {
        "customfield_100": [
          {
            "self": "https://url1001",
            "value": "Mobile",
            "id": "1001",
            "disabled": "false"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations",
      "id": "2",
      "fields": {
        "customfield_100": [
          {
            "self": "https://url1002",
            "value": "Desktop",
            "id": "1002",
            "disabled": false
          },
          {
            "self": "https://url1001",
            "value": "Mobile",
            "id": "1001",
            "disabled": false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations",
      "id": "3",
      "fields": {
        "customfield_100": [
          {
            "self": "https://url1003",
            "value": "ios",
            "id": "1002",
            "disabled": false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations",
      "id": "4",
      "fields": {
        "customfield_100": [
          {
            "self": "https://url1002",
            "value": "Desktop",
            "id": "1002",
            "disabled": false
          },
          {
            "self": "https://url1001",
            "value": "Mobile",
            "id": "1001",
            "disabled": false
          },
          {
            "self": "https://url1003",
            "value": "ios",
            "id": "1003",
            "disabled": false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my part of the code

```
        df2=pd.dataframe()
        d=pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df1['customfield_100'].to_json(orient='record')))
        filtered_component=[]
        for index in range(len(issues.id)):
             if((pd.json_normalize(df1['customfield_100'][index])).size>0):
                 filtered_component.append(d[0][index]['value']
             else:
                 filtered_component.append('No Component')
          df2['Component']=filterd_component
```

When i list df2['Component'], i am getting the below output

```
'Mobile'
'Desktop'
'ios'
'Desktop'
```

I would like my output to be like(when i list df2[components]) i.e if more than single value for customfield_100 then i would like those to be separated by ;. I am not sure how the loop/code should be written for it

```
'Mobile'
'Desktop';'Mobile'
'ios'
'Desktop';'Mobile';'ios'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data, 
    record_path=['issues', 'fields', 'customfield_100'], 
    meta=[['issues', 'id']])

df.groupby('issues.id')['value'].agg(';'.join)
```

where

```
data = {
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations",
      "id": "1",
      "fields": {
        "customfield_100": [
          {
            "self": "https://url1001",
            "value": "Mobile",
            "id": "1001",
            "disabled": False
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations",
      "id": "2",
      "fields": {
        "customfield_100": [
          {
            "self": "https://url1002",
            "value": "Desktop",
            "id": "1002",
            "disabled": False
          },
          {
            "self": "https://url1001",
            "value": "Mobile",
            "id": "1001",
            "disabled": False
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations",
      "id": "3",
      "fields": {
        "customfield_100": [
          {
            "self": "https://url1003",
            "value": "ios",
            "id": "1002",
            "disabled": False
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "operations",
      "id": "4",
      "fields": {
        "customfield_100": [
          {
            "self": "https://url1002",
            "value": "Desktop",
            "id": "1002",
            "disabled": False
          },
          {
            "self": "https://url1001",
            "value": "Mobile",
            "id": "1001",
            "disabled": False
          },
          {
            "self": "https://url1003",
            "value": "ios",
            "id": "1003",
            "disabled": False
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Output:

```
issues.id
1                Mobile
2        Desktop;Mobile
3                   ios
4    Desktop;Mobile;ios
Name: value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If `data` contains your parsed Json data then you can do:

```py
all_data = []
for i in data['issues']:
    for k, v in i['fields'].items():
        for vv in v:
            all_data.append({'main_id': i['id'], 'field_id': k, **vv})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
  main_id         field_id             self    value    id disabled
0       1  customfield_100  https://url1001   Mobile  1001    false
1       2  customfield_100  https://url1002  Desktop  1002    False
2       2  customfield_100  https://url1001   Mobile  1001    False
3       3  customfield_100  https://url1003      ios  1002    False
4       4  customfield_100  https://url1002  Desktop  1002    False
5       4  customfield_100  https://url1001   Mobile  1001    False
6       4  customfield_100  https://url1003      ios  1003    False
```

---

Then you can group by `main_id`, e.g.:

```py
df = df.groupby('main_id')['value'].agg(';'.join)
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
main_id
1                Mobile
2        Desktop;Mobile
3                   ios
4    Desktop;Mobile;ios
Name: value, dtype: object
```